# Understanding DataSource concept

Tags: java, datasource

I'm designing an interface that's going to represent a collection of identifiers of some entities. Going through two similat interfaces jdk provides us with (javadoc ommited):

`javax.sql.DataSource`:

```
public interface DataSource  extends CommonDataSource,Wrapper {

  Connection getConnection() throws SQLException;


  Connection getConnection(String username, String password)
    throws SQLException;

}
```

and `javax.activation.DataSource`:

```
public interface DataSource {

    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException;

    public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException;

    public String getContentType();

    public String getName();
}
```

I decided to write something like that:

```
public interface FilterDataSource{

    public List<Integer> getIdentifiers();

}
```

The interface (I called it `FilterDataSource`, where `Filter` is an entity) may have at least two different implementation `SqlFilterDataSource` and `WebApplicationGlobalCacheFilterDataSource` (they will be created within an `IoC` container).

My question is about the interface. Is that correct to use `DataSource` concept in such a case and if so, how should I redesign it (If it needed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it seems to me from the information you are giving, is that what you are trying to design is more similar to a `DAO` (Data Access Object, see [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object)) or to JPA's `EntityManager` than a `DataSource`. The main difference afaict is that a `DataSource` abstracts completely from the data type it provides (it could very well provide many different types of data, like a database connection would do), while the others do not (or better, to a lesser extent, especially the `EntityManager`). If you need to abstract the access to a list of identifiers of some entity, you don't want (at least I think so) to abstract from the entities themselves, so the `DataSource` is not the best concept you can apply to your design.